# Oracle Developer Tools (ODT) with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: oracle, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2019, 16.11.9, with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio, 19.3.2.0.

I can do a schema compare with my local database, but there are a number of issues I have noticed which I can't have following through to deployment in test or production. I just wondered if I am doing something wrong or if these issues are limitation of the extension.

1. Using schema compare generated change scripts only ever drop and rebuild an existing table, never alter it. This obviously deletes all the data in the table too. How do I change this?
2. Whenever I do a database clean build I have to run the schema compare, or build script, multiple times as the tool doesn't order the build based on dependencies. Surely this is my setup as otherwise this is a HUGE oversight!

Any help welcome.